# Why is my SVG image squeezed in IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm using SVG image files with `<img>` tag. The image looks fine in all browsers except for IE11.

How it should look:
[image: How it should look]

How it looks in IE11:
[image: How it looks in IE11]

The CSS is set to `width:42px; height:auto`. I've tried fiddling with `viewbox` and `height` and `width` of the SVG itself, but nothing seems to help.

This is the code:

```css
.st0{
    fill:#7F7F7F;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="_x33_A4Pmf.tif_1_">
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M38,23.3c0,0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.1,1c-0.2,1.5-0.8,2.8-1.7,4
        c-1.4,1.8-3.2,2.9-5.3,3.3c-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.2-2.1,0.2c-5.8,0-11.7,0-17.5,0c-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.7-0.1c-1.1-0.2-2.1-0.6-3.1-1.2
        c-1.2-0.7-2.2-1.7-3-2.9c-0.7-1.1-1.1-2.3-1.3-3.6c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4
        c0.1-1,0.3-1.9,0.7-2.8c0.4-1,1-1.8,1.7-2.6C5.2,16.8,6,16.2,7,15.7c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.5-1.6,1.4-3.1,2.5-4.4
        c1-1.1,2.1-2,3.4-2.6c1.4-0.7,2.9-1.1,4.5-1.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.1,0.1
        C21.6,7.6,23,8,24.2,8.7c2.5,1.4,4.3,3.4,5.4,6c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1c1.2,0.2,2.2,0.6,3.2,1.2
        c1.2,0.8,2.2,1.7,2.9,2.9c0.7,1.1,1.1,2.3,1.3,3.6C38,22.9,38,23.1,38,23.3z M20,29.8c3,0,6,0,8.9,0c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1-0.1
        c1.3-0.2,2.4-0.8,3.3-1.7c1.3-1.4,1.9-3.1,1.7-5c-0.2-1.3-0.7-2.4-1.6-3.3c-0.9-1-2.1-1.6-3.4-1.8c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.2-0.1
        c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.1-1.2,0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2c-0.6-1.9-1.6-3.4-3.2-4.6c-2-1.5-4.3-2.1-6.8-1.7
        c-1.5,0.2-2.9,0.8-4.2,1.8c-1.4,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.9,4c-0.2,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.4
        c-0.9,0.4-1.6,1-2.2,1.7C5.4,21.2,5,22.5,5,24c0.1,1.4,0.5,2.6,1.4,3.6c1.2,1.4,2.8,2.1,4.6,2.1C14,29.8,17,29.8,20,29.8z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M17,20.7c-0.9,0-1.7,0-2.6,0c1.4-1.9,2.7-3.7,4.1-5.6c1.4,1.9,2.7,3.7,4.1,5.6c-0.9,0-1.7,0-2.6,0
        c0,2,0,4,0,6c-1,0-2,0-3,0C17,24.7,17,22.8,17,20.7z"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please provide a full context in which this SVG is being used. I see a checkbox and some other possible markup/elements you should include in your post. Also include the CSS. Your post should have [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens if you remove `width` from the `<svg>` element?

Comment: @JonathanBowman the same

Comment: same thing is happening to me at this very moment, i had to set the height manually to some pixels value, i'll see if i can find out why that happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a red box that shows the area occupied by svg

`<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="border:1px solid red;" >`

Chrome

[image]

IE11
[image]

If you replace `height:auto`  with a fixed size

```
svg {
width:42px;
height:42px;
}
```

The image will look the same in all browsers:

[image]

**the second variant**: add the viewport to the svg file `width="40" height="40"`

```html
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="border:1px solid red;" >
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#7F7F7F;}
</style>
<g id="_x33_A4Pmf.tif_1_">
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M38,23.3c0,0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.1,1c-0.2,1.5-0.8,2.8-1.7,4
        c-1.4,1.8-3.2,2.9-5.3,3.3c-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.2-2.1,0.2c-5.8,0-11.7,0-17.5,0c-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.7-0.1c-1.1-0.2-2.1-0.6-3.1-1.2
        c-1.2-0.7-2.2-1.7-3-2.9c-0.7-1.1-1.1-2.3-1.3-3.6c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4
        c0.1-1,0.3-1.9,0.7-2.8c0.4-1,1-1.8,1.7-2.6C5.2,16.8,6,16.2,7,15.7c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.5-1.6,1.4-3.1,2.5-4.4
        c1-1.1,2.1-2,3.4-2.6c1.4-0.7,2.9-1.1,4.5-1.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.1,0.1
        C21.6,7.6,23,8,24.2,8.7c2.5,1.4,4.3,3.4,5.4,6c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1c1.2,0.2,2.2,0.6,3.2,1.2
        c1.2,0.8,2.2,1.7,2.9,2.9c0.7,1.1,1.1,2.3,1.3,3.6C38,22.9,38,23.1,38,23.3z M20,29.8c3,0,6,0,8.9,0c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1-0.1
        c1.3-0.2,2.4-0.8,3.3-1.7c1.3-1.4,1.9-3.1,1.7-5c-0.2-1.3-0.7-2.4-1.6-3.3c-0.9-1-2.1-1.6-3.4-1.8c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.2-0.1
        c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.1-1.2,0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2c-0.6-1.9-1.6-3.4-3.2-4.6c-2-1.5-4.3-2.1-6.8-1.7
        c-1.5,0.2-2.9,0.8-4.2,1.8c-1.4,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.9,4c-0.2,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.4
        c-0.9,0.4-1.6,1-2.2,1.7C5.4,21.2,5,22.5,5,24c0.1,1.4,0.5,2.6,1.4,3.6c1.2,1.4,2.8,2.1,4.6,2.1C14,29.8,17,29.8,20,29.8z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M17,20.7c-0.9,0-1.7,0-2.6,0c1.4-1.9,2.7-3.7,4.1-5.6c1.4,1.9,2.7,3.7,4.1,5.6c-0.9,0-1.7,0-2.6,0
        c0,2,0,4,0,6c-1,0-2,0-3,0C17,24.7,17,22.8,17,20.7z"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

**The third variant**

If you want to leave css rule - `height: auto;` for the block, then add "preserveAspectRatio"

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 0 40 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#7F7F7F;} 
svg {
width:42px;
height:auto;
}
```